# C# Web API Project Sharing Strategy

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api2

Currently working with a client that has a Web Api Project/Framework that they use for multiple clients.   98% of the code is reused, but they copy and paste the repository for each new client.   After the copy and paste the only things that really change are Web.Configs and every now and then a couple extensions to the OOTB api. E.g. maybe they standup a custom module to the api `api/rockets/` or they extend an existing api and add some new methods & actions.

I can't find any way to pull this off with .net.  Currently I'm thinking I could solve this via `git` with forks, but I was wondering if there was any way to solve this with .net.  Is there a way to extend an existing web project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach from this one was really simple.  We extracted everything into a common C# Library, converted all of the shared stuff to git submodules.  We then used [Autofac Multitenant](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/multitenant.html) to register some client specific overrides.  It was actually really easy.

Answer (score 2):

The git approach is one way of doing it, but I'd probably go for Nuget packages.

Extract everything that will be common to all solutions, even resources and make a package. 
Take advantage of package versioning and so on. If you got a bug, fix that in the package and simply run a nuget-update in the project, or even just setup your continuous integration to rebuild and update at any dependencies change.

Comment: I want to do this but what about all the stuff that is in the base webproject like startup.cs (owin stuff) , app_start, etc ?

Comment: One of the great features of Nuget is that you can include configurations and even source code and then make transformations in it. https://docs.nuget.org/Create/Configuration-File-and-Source-Code-Transformations . 
Anyway, a trade-off is complexity. Since there's no silver bullet, I suggest always try to keep it as simple as possible. 
If you're having to dig too far in the features of Nuget to get it working, it's probably going to the wrong direction, and if is that the case, that forking approach in git might not be that bad.

Answer (score 0):

One option, would be to have a single web project for multiple clients that uses "Areas".  That way you could turn on/off each are individually.

You could also put your common business logic into a Nuget package and import it for each customer.  But it would be a really bad idea to fork the business logic every time.  What would happen if you found a defect?  You'd be forced to fix the same problem in N projects.

Comment: We have some pretty strict security reqs to keep the envs sep.    Issue for us is its not as simple as just forking the bl we really want to extend it and customize it.  I just can't figure out how to structure it in .net to make it extendable.